# Ubuntu 13.10 numeric pad type wrong numbers

Tags: 13.10, numpad

After upgrading to 13.10 my numeric pad type number 1 instead of 7, number 2 instead of 8 and number 3 instead of 9, numbers 4,5 and 6 are OK. Any idea?

Comment: File a bug report, this is very abnormal.

Comment: broken keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

There was an option in 13.04, in Keyboard -> layout Options (accessible through Region and language -> Layout -> Options too). Your one was probably ATM/Phone-style.

[image: Keypad options]

I do not know if in the simplification-frenzy on 13.10 it has simply moved in another window of it has been culled. You can add yourself to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1245064.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04: it's now called "Gnome Tweaks". May need to install it through the "Ubuntu Software" app.

Answer (score 1):

had same problem and used gnome tweak tool

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool -y && gnome-tweak-tool
```

go to typing-> numpad and disable phone numpad style

Comment: Do gnome-tweak-tool works in Unity too? I am not sure if the OP is working under Gnome, Unity or whatever...

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04: it's now called "Gnome Tweaks". May need to install it through the "Ubuntu Software" app.